# Symfony Check if user exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am looking for a solution in my controller to check before sending a form if the user already exists in the database. Here is my action on which I would like to implement this.

```
/**
 * Creates a new invite entity.
 *
 * @Route("/inscription", name="invite_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $invite = new Invite();

    $form = $this->createForm(InviteType::class, $invite);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($invite);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('app_mailer')->sendMailInscriptionMjml($invite, $this->getParameter('client_mail_to'));

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Votre inscription à été pris en compte.');
        } else {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Une erreur est survenue.');
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('invite_show', array('id' => $invite->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('@App/invite/new.html.twig', array(
        'invite' => $invite,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this in the controller. This is basic entity validation and Symfony comes with built in constraints to handle this sort of thing.

Assuming you are using a User Entity similar to below in your Symfony application you need only apply a unique validation constraint to the user class and specify which properties you want to test against for uniqueness.  This example will validate that the user is *unique by email*, and throw an exception if not.

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/** @UniqueEntity(
  * fields={"email"},
  * errorPath="email",
  * message="It appears you have already registered with this email."
  *)
  */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    // ...
}
```

Pay notice to the `@UniqueEntity("email")` annotation on the class and the use statements. Of course you'll need to adopt this logic to your user class.

```
// controller action
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $invite = new Invite();

    $form = $this->createForm(InviteType::class, $invite);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($invite);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('app_mailer')->sendMailInscriptionMjml(
              $invite, $this->getParameter('client_mail_to')
            );

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
              ->add('success', 'Votre inscription à été pris en compte.');

            return $this->redirect(
              $this->generateUrl(
                'invite_show', array(
                  'id' => $invite->getId()
                )
              )
            );
         }
    }

    return $this->render('@App/invite/new.html.twig', array(
        'invite' => $invite,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**For more on this:**

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: I am trying to warn the user that he is already registered.
Thanks

Comment: you can do that with this set up. It's what its for.

Comment: It validates that there are no other users with that email already in your database.  Then throws the exception if it finds one.  The point is, you don't have to write a query in your controller to do this.  I've updated the annotation to show you can even include your own custom error message if you want.

Comment: Thank you but I have nothing that appears in message on screen. I have to add something to my controller?
Thank you

Comment: it's hard for me to say without seeing  your complete set up. This example assumes you have an "email" property on your Invite entity class, that you've set up the annotations correctly and are rendering your form properly in twig. Are you seeing an exception in your profiler?

Comment: I put my controller on top and here is my twig

Comment: it's best if you edit your original question and not keep posting changes to it as answers :)  Have you added the validation constraint to your Invite entity? And the use statements? are you seeing errors in your profiler?

Comment: Yes it's true forgive me. Yes I have added what you told me but I have no error in return except that it goes into the else of my controller.

Comment: you should be able to get rid of that else.  You don't need the flash bag for your error since you've defined it in your constraint.  Are your errors bubbling?  Again, I'll ask do you see the exception in your profiler??

Comment: I made an edit to your controller (in my answer above). You had your return statement which redirected to the invite_show route *outside* of your isValid method.  Therefore it would go to invite_show wether it was valid or not.  You only want to go to that if it is valid, otherwise you stay with new.html.twig and are shown the exception.  Also get rid of that pre submit event handler if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you it works however you can display it elsewhere than below the email input? like a flashbag.

Comment: Yes you can specify where to point the error in the annotation or you can set error bubbling in your form so that the exception bubbles.  If you do that make sure you have ((form_errors(form)}} in your template.  Read up on validation constraints and forms in the Symfony cookbook.

Comment: Hello, does this work without Doctrine? Im using Symfony with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. Can I assert existing email in entity like this too? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// Pass in the entity manager to your form via options
// Do this before you call $this->createForm:
// $options['entityManager'] = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// then call $form = $this->createForm(InviteType::class, $invite, $options);

// Inside your form type i.e. InviteType
$em = $options['entityManager'];

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $user = $data['user']; // this needs to be whatever you called user in your form
        $userRepo = $em->getRepository('User'); // this needs to be the location of your user repository
        if ($userRepo->findOneBy(['user' => $user])) { // you need to pick a field that determines how you will search for the user via the repository
            $form->addError(new FormError('User already exists'));
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container accroche">
    <h5>{{ 'Inscription aux évenements'|trans }}</h5>
    <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500,
        quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique,
        sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment,
        par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.
    </p>
</div>
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate','id':'formValidate'}}) }}
<div class="middle">
    <div class="middle_form">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="stepwizard">
                <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="stepwizard-step col-md-3">
                        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stepwizard-step col-md-3">
                        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stepwizard-step col-md-3">
                        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stepwizard-step col-md-3">
                        <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>{{ 'Informations invités'|trans }}</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'last_name'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                            <label for="last_name">{{ 'Nom'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.surname, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'surname'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.surname) }}
                            <label for="surname">{{ 'Prénom'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'email'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                            <label for="email">{{ 'E-mail'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label>{{ 'Présence'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.dispo, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'dispo'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.dispo) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">{{ 'SUIVANT'|trans }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>{{ 'Informations participants'|trans }}</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="customers"
                            data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.customers.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                            {% for customers in form.customers %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col-12">
                                        {{ form_row(customers.name, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'name'}}) }}
                                        {{ form_errors(customers.name) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col-12">
                                        {{ form_row(customers.surname, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'id': 'surname'}}) }}
                                        {{ form_errors(customers.surname) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col-12">
                                        {{ form_row(customers.old) }}
                                        {{ form_errors(customers.old) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">{{ 'PRECEDENT'|trans }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">{{ 'SUIVANT'|trans }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Logements</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.housing, {'attr': {'class':'validate'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.housing) }}
                            <label>{{ 'Comment allez vous vous logez ?'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.hotel, {'attr': {'class':'validate'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.hotel) }}
                            <label>{{ 'Hôtel'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">{{ 'PRECEDENT'|trans }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">{{ 'SUIVANT'|trans }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>{{ 'Arrivée/Départ'|trans }}</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label>{{ 'Date d\'arrivée'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                            {#<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="dateArrival" name="form[dateArrival]"/>#}
                            {{ form_widget(form.dateArrival, {'attr': {'class': 'datepicker validate'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.dateArrival) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label>{{ 'Date de départ'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                            {#<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="dateDeparture" name="form[dateDeparture]"/>#}
                            {{ form_widget(form.dateDeparture, {'attr': {'class': 'datepicker validate'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.dateDeparture) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col-12">
                            {{ form_widget(form.transport, {'attr': {'class':'validate'}}) }}
                            {{ form_errors(form.transport) }}
                            <label>{{ 'Transport utilisé'|trans }} <sup>*</sup></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">{{ 'PRECEDENT'|trans }}</button>
                    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class':'btn btn-success', 'id':'SaveAccount'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{ form_widget(form.dateArrival, {'attr': {'class': 'hidden'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.dateDeparture, {'attr': {'class': 'hidden'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, get the id `$id = #YourId;`. You can then select the user using SQL. `SELECT * FROM [user_table] WHERE id = $id;` If the result holds a user, then the user exists.

Comment: I create my request directly in the controller or in the repository? thanks

Comment: You would run it as an SQL statement.